# Automatically start apps after ending call

Tags: android

We have call log or phone apps in every android device for calling facility by which we dial number or call any number to talk. I have also another application name apps-1 (build by me). My main requirement is when user will make a call with anyone and after ending of each call my apps will open automatically. How can I do that it in programmatically in Android.

Comment: adding into your question that `It's very urgent.` doesn't achieve anything, everyone here is doing this on their own time and helping because they want to

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a service open (in foreground). 
It will listen to phone call states. Once the phone state is OFF_HOOK you prepare your service to be started and when the subsequent state of CALL_STATE_IDLE comes you launch your activity.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

```
   boolean phoneDialed = false;
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

            if (phoneDialed = true) {
                // Start your activity

                // Make it false again for next use
                phoneDialed = false;
            }
        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            phoneDialed = true;
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
```

Comment: can i get some code related to this ? can you provide me some code ?

Comment: Thanks brother . i will try it